# UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification and UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification not always triggered in Unity iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have created an Unity iOS App. The reason I have created the App on unity is because it can be easily ported to other platforms.

I am communicating with `Axivity Sensors` via BLE technology. Everything is working fine. But now I want to run the app in background. So for that I found that I should use `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` and `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` notifications so that I can do some background processing.

**But sometimes I am not notified when App becomes active or deactive.**

Is there anything that I am doing wrong or is there a better way to do that ?

Following is the code:

```
-(id) init {

    self = [super init];

    if (!self) return nil;

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillResignActive:) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidBecomeActive:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillTerminate:) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];

        return self;
    }

-(void)appWillResignActive:(NSNotification*)note {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(BLEOnCharactersticsUpdateNotification:)
                                             name:BLEOnCharactersticsUpdate object:nil]; 
}

-(void)appDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification*)note {

    NSLog(@"AppDidBecomeActive ");

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:BLEOnCharactersticsUpdate object:nil];

    for(int timeStampIndex = 0; timeStampIndex < [timeStampArray count]; timeStampIndex++) {

        NSLog(@"TimeStamp %i : Value : %@",timeStampIndex,[timeStampArray objectAtIndex:timeStampIndex]);
    }
}

-(void)appWillTerminate:(NSNotification*)note {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];
}
```

Comment: Which version of unity you are using ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless Unity 5.4.0 f3

Comment: The snippet you posted here, is this the auto generated code taken from unity->xcode export or you wrote it yourself in xcode ?

Comment: its mine, I wrote this in separate class

Comment: Did you find AppDelegate class in your project, these application functions are the part of that class if you are defining it somewhere else, first make sure it is being called in app delegate as per the expectation and then pass message from AppDelegate to your written code. Also, in unity we have facility to check background mode `http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/948464/how-can-i-know-is-runinbackground.html` can you accomplish your need from here ?

Comment: Yes, they also don't work every time. Tried opening the link, it says page not found.

Comment: A quick question, did you check the capabilities tab in your project setting and enable background mode? Also please check when it is expected and not calling active/inactive events, is it calling didfinishlaunching function ? For broken link you can check this link as well: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/329615/how-to-know-when-my-game-is-in-background.html

Comment: Yes, I did enable Use Bluetooth LE Accessories. Upon further debugging I found they are being called but takes a lot of time for them to be called. Thats very strange.

Answer (score 1):

How do you guarantee that the object from the code sample exists during whole application lifecycle? 
Most likely, it's deallocated at some point of execution, that's why it doesn't receive the notifications. iOS itself guarantees that the app always receives at least `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` and `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`.

P.S.You subscribe for notifications in `init` method. And unsubscribe in `appWillTerminate`. A better place to unsubscribe would be `dealloc`.